# How to embed shrinkroute url() call in jade template hrefs?

Tags: node.js, express, shrinkroute

How do I translate the examples from the shrinkroute README file:

```
// or views...
<a href="<%= url( "user", { id: 1 }) %>">User profile</a>
<a href="<%= fullUrl( "user", { id: 1 }) %>">User profile</a>
```

for use in jade templates?
For example, something like

```
a(href="#{ url( "user", { id: 1 }) }") User profile
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, ensure that you're using the shrinkroute middleware:

```
app.use( shrinkr.middleware );
```

It'll automatically provide you the following helpers:

- `req.buildUrl` and `res.locals.url` - builds paths for a route. The same as using `shrinkr.url()`.
- `req.buildFullUrl` and `res.locals.fullUrl` - builds full URLs for a route. The same as using `shrinkr.fullUrl()`.

In Jade, you simply have to use the following:

```
a(href=url( "user", { id: 1 } )) My Username
a(href=fullUrl( "user", { id: 1 } )) My Username
```

Rendered output:

```
<a href="/user/1">My Username</a>
<a href="http://localhost/user/1">My Username</a>
```

The above output will depend on the routes you have named in your shrinkroute instance.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the creator of Shrinkroute.

Answer (score 2):

here's a general solution for calling a function from within a template; see @gustavohenke 's answer for a specific solution for how to use shrinkroute's built-in `locals.buildFullUrl` function within a jade template

```
// node.js
var url = require('url');
// Set up locals.shrinkUrl for every request
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.shrinkUrl = function(path, queryObject){
    var out = url.format({
      pathname: path,
      query: queryObject,
    });
    return out;
  };
  next();
});

// template.jade
a(href=locals.shrinkUrl("user", {id: 1}) ) User profile

// rendered
<a href='/user?id=1'>User profile</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Plato. However, the goal is to call the shrinkroute.url() method from the jade template to create the url from the route named "user", using the passed params. I'm just not sure this is suppored for jade.

Comment: Edited to demonstrate calling functions from templates. You could probably also set `locals.shrinkUrl = shrinkUrl.url` in node if you want to use an existing function

Comment: @Plato, I've read the history of your answer; the `url` function returns _only_ the path and query string part of the url. `fullUrl` returns the whole url, including protocol and host.

Comment: Also, shrinkroute is far more powerful than the builtin `url.format`, it'll look for Express params if any, while you don't have to rewrite the same url various times across the project.